# Access to resources on web application classpath

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, ant, web.xml

Under `WEB-INF/classes` folder i have java class files structured in package hierarchy(e.g: `com.company.app`) and `resources` folder that contains spring context xml, `jdbc.properties` file, `log4j.properties` file and other resources that I use in mu app. To load spring context and configure log4j in `web.xml`  i use

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param> 
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

and in `applicationContext.xml` I use property-placeholder to locate `jdbc.properties` file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>
```

However tomcat says that that classpath resource can not be resolved. I use ant to build a war file and have next target to compile java sources and copy evererything except java sources from src folder to `WEB-INF/classes`

```
<target name="javac" description="Compile java source to bytecode">
        <mkdir dir="${war_web_inf}/classes" />
        <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8" destdir="WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" source="1.5" target="1.5" nowarn="true" debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
        </javac>
        <copy todir="${war_web_inf}/classes">
            <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.java" />
        </copy>

    </target>
```

How can I have access to resources in web.xml as classpath:log4j.properties for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents of your resources dir should be copied directly to WEB-INF/classes, so if your structure is:

```
src/
  java/
  resources/
```

You should use something like

```
<copy todir="${war_web_inf}/classes">
  <fileset dir="src/resources" />
</copy>
```